# Can't find a collection

Tags: hair, collections, file-browser, viewlayers

I have a collection (called "SCATTER: Tree1") with an object inside, and I can't seem to find them in the view layer. I've tried to activate some restriction toggles that can sometimes hide what you're looking for, but it didn't really help. The reason I know it exists is because I can find them in the Blender File search, which you can see in this first image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It doesn't seem to be something linked to another project, since there are no "libraries" options in the Blender File search.

This collection is being used as a hair particle.

Blender 2.81

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunatelly I can't.

Comment: So you can`t find the object in the viewport? but its name is visible in the outliner?

Comment: In the outliner, I can find them in the "Blender File" option, as you see in the image. But I can't find it in the "view layer", which is the normal default window of the outliner.

Comment: I think it's no very clear what you need... The view layer is the active workspace. You are showing a first image of the outliner showing the  "SCATTER: Tree1" but you said that you can't find that on that same outliner. can you add an image showing what you refer as the "VIew layer" and the issue there?

Comment: I just added a 3rd image. The outliner has many types of windows (I don't really know how to explain in better words) that you can choose. The default one is "View Layer". That's where I can't find my collection. If I go to "Blender file" (which is a place in the outliner used to search for meshes, materials and all types of files that are in the project), I can find it, and that's what I'm showing in the 1st image.

Comment: Do you use more Scenes than default one?

Comment: Is called "display mode" and i don't see any way to hide (like disappear) a collection from a display mode, try to open your file in a new scene, also try to use the search bar that is on the top of the outliner. But it could be a bug

Comment: well I use the default scene. Opening in a new scene doesnt change anything. I can find the object in search bar but I can't select it. Meaning it's somehow hidden with the restriction toggles, even though I've already activated them all and tried to search again.

Comment: As suggested by Chris ... attach your blend, delete all objects from View Layers (to make file lighter) and keep just the issued Collection ... use https://blend-exchange.com given code copy-paste into your question via Edit. Thanks

Comment: @vklidu sorry but I don't have permission to share the blend file. I'm not trying to make things difficult, there's just nothing I can do about that.